# Nested Split with str_tok in C

Tags: c

I have a string in C that i want to split in str_tok
String is = `04_1,03_0,05_1`
It works fine if split once.

```
        char* token = strtok(argv[2], ",");
        

        while (token != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ","); }
```

It will get `04_1 03_0 05_1`
I want to split it again with the `_` underscore  as the delimiter

***SOLUTION FOUND***

```
char* token = strtok(argv[2], "_,");
token = strtok(NULL, "_,");
```

Comment: If you set the delimiter to `"_,"`, the output will be `04 1 03 0 05 1`. Is that what you want?

Comment: take care about strtok will change the original string and must be avoided on constant strings, like argv must be

Comment: @r043v: [This documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) states that the `argv` strings are modifiable, and it explicitly states that you can use `strtok` on them.

Comment: @user3386109 Oh wow, i didn't know you can do that.., yup that's exactly what i need. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `strtok` multiple deliminators:

```
token = strtok(NULL, ",_");
```

I guess that will give you:

```
04 1 03 0 05 1
```

If that helps?

Otherwise, https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r says `strtok_r` is the reentrant version.

Personally, I'd probably just do it in two separate steps and avoid nesting it.

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c covers some more C++ ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much!